# Read real time data from other websites

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I need a function on my website so that it can update the sports data, for example, the result of a sports game in real time. I have seen some websites do that, but I don't know how to monitoring those data. Any suggestions or help?

Comment: Give more detail, share some code what have you done so far? Saying need function is very generic, do you need API, sample code, Azure Function?

Answer (score 1):

There are 4 possible approaches for displaying real-time data on website:

1. **Refresh page** at periodic intervals

   - Obsolete method. Not recommended for modern apps.
2. **AJAX** calls from browser to pull data at periodic intervals

   - This is the most popular method used currently by many websites
   - Can be done with least development effort.

**3. Websocket**

- Modern method. Used extensively in financial services domain.
- Good for bi-directional communication between client and server.
- Adds an unnecessary overhead for simple updates by server (Example: match score)

**4. SSE (Server-Sent-Events)**

- Most modern of all methods. Quickly gaining adoption.
- Least overhead.
- Most preferred for near real-time update from server to client.

**More information on SSE:**

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/server-sent-events/

Comment: I can use Signalr to push data from the server, but how can I monitoring and retrieve these data sources from online update websites.